# How to write consoleLog to a file in an exported application?

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, console, rcp

I used `System.setOut(stream)` to redirect console outputs, where stream writes to console and to a file. When I run it through Eclipse it does write everything to the file including exceptions (running it with -consoleLog parameter). But when I run the exported application I want it to also save exception trace to a file, which does not work. How do I redirect consoleLog output to the console? Or how to otherwise redirect consoleLog outputs to a file?